# Uso correcto del método GET en formulario (HTML Y PHP)

Tags: php, html

pues tengo un pequeño inconveniente que me está dando dolores de cabeza espero alguien me pueda ayudar a identificar mi error, de antemano muchas gracias. El asunto es:

Tengo un pequeño buscador:

```html
<form action="search" method="GET" autocomplete="off">
 <input type="text" name='texto' class="form-control" placeholder="texto a buscar" required>
    <select class="form-control"  name="ciudad" required>
     <option value="1">Opcion 1</option>
        <option value="2">Opcion 1</option>
    </select>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Buscar">Buscar</button>
</form>
```

La idea es que este pequeño buscador realice las búsquedas utilizando el parámetro GET para poder tener un enlace de búsqueda.

Mediante .htaccess y php estoy creando enlaces dinámicos. Mediante .htacces indico que plantilla mostrar. Lo hago de esta manera:

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteRule  ^search ?search [L]
```

**Controlador**

```
elseif(isset($_GET['search'])){
 $respuesta = Paginas::PlantillaBusqueda();
}
```

**Gestor de plantillas**

```
public static function PlantillaBusqueda(){
   $incluir = "views/plantillas/busqueda/index.php";
   return $incluir;
}
```

Todo lo anterior para que mi enlace de búsqueda quede con la siguiente estructura (por favor especial atención en el parámetro **?search**):

**http://localhost/miproyecto/?search&texto=asdas&ciudad=18**

Si accedo al proyecto con esa URL sin problema me detecta los parámetros "texto y ciudad"

El problema es el siguiente:

Al hacer uso del formulario, este me está enviando al siguiente enlace, y de esta manera no puedo leer los parámetros GET :( ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal? :

**http://localhost/miproyecto/search?texto=asdas&ciudad=18**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias de antemano por su ayuda. Un abrazo.

Comment: prueba dejando en blanco el parámetro **action** del formulario y crea un campo oculto cuyo nombre sea **search** y dejas el valor en blanco, prueba de nuevo y cuéntanos

Comment: Gracias carlos por tu comentario, fíjate que ya lo había intentado, sin embargo, no estoy del todo a gusto, pues al hacer esto (enviar "search" como parámetro oculto) me pone un signo de "=" ¿habrá forma de quitarlo enviarlo solo como parámetro? Mira, https://prnt.sc/jcmh98

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías controlarlo con jquery, sería algo así:

```
<form action="search" method="GET" id="form" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="text" name='texto' class="form-control" placeholder="texto a buscar" required>
    <select class="form-control"  name="ciudad" required>
        <option value="">Seleccione</option>
        <option value="1">Opcion 1</option>
        <option value="2">Opcion 1</option>
    </select>
    <input id="submit-hidden" type="submit" style="display: none" />

    <button type="submit" id="enviar" class="btn btn-primary" value="Buscar">Buscar</button>
</form>
```

y con Jquery:

```js
$(function(){
  $("#enviar").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var texto = $("input[name=texto]").val();
    var ciudad = $("select[name=ciudad]").val();
    if (!$("#form")[0].checkValidity()) {
      $("#form").find("#submit-hidden").click();
    }else{
      window.location.href="http://localhost/miproyecto/?search&texto="+texto+"&ciudad="+ciudad

    }


  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="search" method="GET" id="form" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="text" name='texto' class="form-control" placeholder="texto a buscar" required>
    <select class="form-control"  name="ciudad" required>
        <option value="">Seleccione</option>
        <option value="1">Opcion 1</option>
        <option value="2">Opcion 1</option>
    </select>
    <input id="submit-hidden" type="submit" style="display: none" />

    <button type="submit" id="enviar" class="btn btn-primary" value="Buscar">Buscar</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Pfff, sos un crack Carlos! Muchas gracias, así funciona de maravilla!  gracias por tu respuesta y sobre todo por tu tiempo. Un abrazo.

Comment: Posdata estimado Carlos: Hay manera de lanzar las alertas de los campos requeridos desde jquery. Me refiero a estas: https://prnt.sc/jcnowe  lo que pasa es que usando tu código no encuentro como hacer esas validaciones y lanzar esas notificaciones : ( ¿Necesitaría abrir otro hilo? ¡Gracias infinitas!

Comment: @NeftaliAcosta Hola que tal, no es necesario, edite mi respuesta con la posible solución a lo que planetas, con un par de cambios ya quedan las alertas, Saludos

Comment: Carlos funciona a la maravilla, justo lo que te comentaba que necesitaba. Buscaré documentación sobre la función checkValidity que es la que noto que hace la mágia ya que yo me estaba llendo por el camino largo ( notificar a través de modal las validaciones, cosas que no me estaba gustando como quedaba.) Por tu tiempo  y por todo muchas gracias.